# How to make python actually combine unicode characters?

Tags: python, unicode

So I have been working on a project that requires me to put an overline on top of some data. To do that, I was going to use an unicode Combining Overline character (U+0305). However, the combine function does not seem to be working - no matter what I do, it just puts an overline next to a character, not on top of it. Meanwhile, Combining Underline (and any other ones, such as U+0304 and U+0306) do work as intended(screenshot attached).
[Misbehaving overline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfE2C.png)
[Working underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMelu.png)

I tried both normal print and normalize(), but the output the same result. So what am I missing?

My test code:

```
from unicodedata import normalize
char = 'X'
accent = '\u0305'  #\u0332 for underline
print(normalize("NFC", accent + char))
print(accent + char)
```

Result:

```
‾X
‾X
```

If I swap accent and char, so that the combining character follows a base character, it changes the size of the base character like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvjSz.png), but overline still does not go into place. I tried both PyCharm terminal and cmd, but they give me the same result.

Comment: The accent comes after the letter, but combining isn't done by Python, but the terminal/IDE used, so you may still have an issue.  Here's accent before: ̅X and accent after: X̅ which may or may not work on your browser.  The latter looks fine on Chrome for me, but the former is applied to the space before the X.  Try a different IDE.

Comment: @MarkTolonen this makes sense, but underline works just fine, and so do other accents that put something on top of a character, like ˘ or ^

Comment: Try A (accent) B where the accent isn't the first thing on the line.

Comment: Not sure how this will render in the comment box, but... On my linux system running the python shell (aka repl), it highlighted the newline so ended up on the line above: `print(normalize("NFC", accent + char))̅
`

Comment: Straight from [unicode.org](https://unicode.org/faq/char_combmark.html) "A combining character sequence is a base character followed by any number of combining characters."  Doing something undefined is undefined...it may work, it may not.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I did, and it got even more weird: it reduced the size of the first character [screenshot](https://imgur.com/a/alCZzQ7), but overline still went in between.

Comment: Maybe try a different font? For me, using IDLE on windows, `char + accent` works fine (though `accent + char` looks worse).

Comment: @JohnColeman Looks like you are right... I could not get my IDLE to show it, but some online compiler did work as expected. I find this extremely weird as I was expecting unicode to work the same everywhere, but I guess that is what we got. Should I post this as an answer?

Comment: I was just guessing. Unicode support can be spotty. If you have something clear enough to post as an answer, go for it.